# Bipolar transistors that only connect via base to emitter

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, power-electronics, ground, negative-voltage

I am trying to understand how to use this configuration of the LTC2992 power measure IC and the only part I am confused with so far is the two transistors which I have circled.

[image]

What I know so far about this part is the ORGND will change between being rather ground or a maximum of -95V. The GPIO pins are set to input they are both open drain. I don't understand the point of these transistors even after going through the datasheet unless I have missed something. I only theory is that they are acting as diodes so far. Heres a link to the datasheet

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc2992.pdf

The IC itself is meant to be able to sense the power across the sense resistor and then send this data to a master.

Comment: my best guess: they wanted a pair of matched diodes.

Comment: As the notes state "MAX EMITTER-BASE BREAKDOWN VOLTAGE OF Q4, Q5 SHOULD BE LESS THAN 7V" they may be protection (sacrificial) devices.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can't be matched. Those have only one device per package. The LTC4371 is for a dual negative supply (as its VSS) while the LTC2992 is a positive supply device. The first two GPIOs are for monitoring the two supplies.

Comment: @PeterSmith I don't think they are sacrificial. They are depending on the fact that BJTs (and in particular these BJTs) will avalanche when their base-emitter junctions are sufficiently reverse-biased. They are preceded by a resistor divider that seriously divides down the voltage that is followed by a seriously sized current limit resistor, as well. So the BJT avalanche is strongly current-limited and won't damage them.

Comment: Trak, do you understand what the LTC4371 does and what the LTC2992 is doing, as well? If not, then those BJTs will be difficult to explain. But if you do understand what those two ICs are there for, then the two BJTs aren't hard to understand.

Comment: @jonk Yeah I know that the LTC4371 is a negative or diode IC which compares VOUT with the ground connected to Q3 and will output which ever is more negative so the ORGND will be switching from ground to the negative voltage presented at Q2. LTC2992 is measuring the power across the sense resistor and communicating that to a master.

Comment: @trak What is the purpose of GPIO1 and GPIO2, from the datasheet, and what role do they play in measuring power?

Comment: @jonk from what I know GPIO1 and GPIO2 are set to input and they measure input voltage. Depending on whether GPIO1 or GPIO2 is higher this will tell the LTC2992 whether its should be looking to measure a negative or positive voltage across the sense resistor.